# MVC Resource Can not be found After Publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Web Application.

When I am running the application from my code, that works fine and I am able to go any pages.

However I publish it on IIS, It gives the error:

> The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
> are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
> had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
> the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

And the URL Changes like below:

> `http://localhost/IssuerScripting_Web/%23/%23`

However the path is

> http://localhost/IssuerScripting_Web/UserRoleManagement/User_Management

EDIT: Here is my RouteConfig in below.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Dashboards", action = "Dashboard_1", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );



            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Password",
                url: "AdminUserPasswordCreate/PasswordCreate/{id}/",
                defaults: new { controller = "AdminUserPasswordCreate", action = "CreatedPassword", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


        }
```

And the below is the controller of Dashboard:

```
public class DashboardsController : BaseController //BaseController 
    {
        public ActionResult Dashboard_1()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

What might be causing this issue?

My default login page is working fine. But this page is like a main page and has all the Menu Items.

I was able to publish it earlier, and was working when I publish. I am not able to figure out the issue.

I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: Are you able to view any resource when it's been published to IIS?

Comment: I am able to see my login page and works to log me in. So yes

Comment: Can you show the controller action? Are you using attribute routing? Can you also share your route config?

Comment: Hey @DavidMcEleney I edit the question and added the controller and routeconfig. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To whom has this problem, After several hours I figured out that Scripts files were not pasting properly when I published it.

I removed the Scripts, Styles, Content folders from my project and added them back.

Then I published and it worked!